What is the main benefit from NgModule in Angular 17
Now with Angular 17 I understand that you don't need to use the NgModule to run the different components in the application, because you can import them in the app.component.ts. With this approach; what is the main benefit of keep using the NgModule on your app?

Probably it will be, code optimization like Code organization to help organize your code, lazy loading.

@JoseVicente lazy loading is totally possible with standalone. It's even much more powerful with @defer. Also in my experience, modules don't help much with organizing code.

In new Angular apps, you should only use standalone components. Everything which can be done with NgModules, can also be done with standalone components/pipes/directives, but not vice versa. The key benefits of standalone are:

Less code and smaller bundle size (especially with v19)
Only standalone directives can be added to hostDirectives
Only standalone components can be deferred
Reporting of unused imports only works in standalone components

The only case I see where NgModules might be beneficial, is when you have a big feature consisting of several components/directives/pipes. Here a module can help to collect them, instead of needing to import all separately.
For example, if you have a complex table feature and always need to import the following components:
imports: [
  MyTableComponent,
  MyTableHeaderRowComponent,
  MyTableRowComponent,
  // ...
]

Here it would be easier if there was a module:
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MyTableComponent,
    MyTableHeaderRowComponent,
    MyTableRowComponent,
    // ...
  ]
})
export class MyTableModule {}

And when using the feature you could simply import MyTableModule.
The individual components however should be standalone nevertheless, for the reasons mentioned above.

I think there might be a small misunderstanding. With Standalone Components in Angular, you don't actually need to import them into App.component.ts. The key benefit is that Standalone Components are self-contained, meaning you can directly use them in templates or reference them in other components without needing an intermediary NgModule.
The idea of "importing into App.component.ts" makes more sense when you're dealing with components inside a traditional NgModule, where you would register components in the module. However, Standalone Components work independently, so there's no need for that extra step.
Regarding the benefits of NgModules, they offer fine-grained control over things like dependency injection, routing, and lazy loading, which is especially useful in larger, more modular applications.

However, I recommend using Standalone Components for the following
reasons:

Better performance (due to less overhead) Less boilerplate (no need
to manage NgModules for simple components)


